# Data in transit encryption for azure-kusto-spark connector

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am currently trying to verify that the azure-kusto-spark connector encrypts data in transit.  However, I do not see anywhere in documentation that specifies what protocol the connector utilizes.

Could I get the answer to that question and have it added to documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure kusto connector uses Https (TLS 1.2) to communicate with kusto or azure storage